# Check for duplicate val in url string

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I've url string and I want to know if it contains duplicate like port more then one time for example in this case 54001 or 77777 is exist more than one time?
I've lo-dash and underscore js

http://gr-t6fa45e73.go.grp.corp:54001/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fro-d3ma32e85.mo.grp.corp%3A77777%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=zs6.node&test=54001

Comment: Why i can't see `54001 or 77777` twice in URL?

Comment: @Manwal - done edit my question

Comment: 77777 is not a valid port number, but never mind that. Do you simply want to see if the both the value of "test" _and_ a port number are specified, and if so perform some action? Oh, I see, if the port is specified in the actual request as well as in the redirect... is that it?

Comment: @theglossy1 - yep ,pls ignore the port number this is for example,I need to find duplicate in port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? This pure JS function try to search url params that matches with url ports

```js
function search() {
    var url = unescape(document.getElementById("url").innerHTML); 
    var patternPort = /:\d+/g;    
    var ports = url.match(patternPort);

    for (i=0; i<ports.length; i++){
       var patternParam= new RegExp("=" + ports[i].substr(1), 'g');
       if(url.match(patternParam)){
          alert(ports[i].substr(1) + " is repeated");
       }
    }        
}
```

```html
<pre id="url">http://gr-t6fa45e73.go.grp.corp:54001/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fro-d3ma32e85.mo.grp.corp%3A77777%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=zs6.node&test=54001</pre>
<button onclick="search()">Search repeated ports on params</button>
```